# In VBA, help to create a code to run the button in HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba, button

HTML of Website

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

The codes i have tried which is an error are as follows:

```vba
doc.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary").Item(1).Click

idoc.querySelector("input[type*=submit]").Click

doc.getElementsByValue("Submit").Click
```

I would like to get a code which will run the VBA to click the button as per the HTML

Comment: Please update with a more-complete code listing, and explain exactly what you mean by "error".  If you get errors it's useful to say *what* errors they were...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.